# Access 2007 using a DAO recordset to add record to the END of a table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a report template in Word that pulls tables from an Access 2007 database.  The tables should be exactly structured as they should appear in the report since we want to do a minimal amount of post-processing a formatting after updating the fields in the template.

In one step I use some VBA and a DAO.RecordSet to add a TOTAL row to the bottom of the table.  The last bit there under "Add the total row" is where the row is added.

I want this row to be the LAST row in the table so when we update the fields in the Word report we don't have to move it around.  About 90% of the time it works all the time :) but occasionally it will put the Total row at the top.  I'm not sure how to force it to the bottom of the table.  Any hints or workarounds?

I've found a SQL statement is even worse, it almost always adds the total row to the top.

Thanks!

```
'Add the total row.
rs1.MoveLast
rs1.AddNew
rs1.Fields(fname) = "Total"
rs1.Fields("Frequency") = TotalSum
rs1.Fields("Percent") = "100.0%"
rs1.Update

rs1.Close
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a relational database, there is no such thing as first or last, only an order that you impose with a field on which to sort. This is often an ID or date. Add a suitable field and then sort by that field when extracting the data. When adding a record, make sure it fits in the sequence you want by updating the sort field.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I thought about that.  However, if I add a sort field then that sort field will be pulled into the report as well.  If I add a sort field, sort the table, then remove the field, would it preserve that order or does not not make any sense with a relational database?

Comment: With a query, you can sort on a field without having it as part of the result set. There is no point adding a field, sorting, and removing the field, because you are back to the same situation of not knowing in what order the records will be returned. Just because the look right for this week or month does not mean that there will be right next week.